# What shape should value prop have? (v1.x)

Tags: react-select

v1.x
What should I set as a value prop for `Select.Async` to have it work properly.

I have options defined as array of `{value,label}` pairs. Doeas that mean that value prop should also be shaped like that (with multi) prop.
I cannot find anything about that in documentation.

I set value to just array of integers, (and value key in options is as well an integer of course) everything works till moment I reload the page (remount component) and start changing the input. Then everything is gone. Works perfectly with objects.

Is my assumption correct that value has to be also `{value,label}` object/array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is not correct. The `value` prop does not have to be of type `object`.

Here is its [type definition from the documentation](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/tree/v1.x#select-props):

> Property | Type  | Default      | Description
>
> value      | **any**    | undefined | initial field value

If you want to use an object, you don´t have to follow the assumption that you need `value` and `label` attributes in the objects representing your options. If you set the `labelKey` and `valueKey` props to the specific attribute names, you can use any combination of attributes representing `value` and `label`.

Comment: So how does react-select match selected options? Comparing value to each option by valueKey?

Comment: Yes. At first it will map your `value`prop to an existing option in the `options` array if your value is not of type `object`, otherwise it will just use the object you provided inside the `value` prop.
Then it will use comparison by valueKey for either highlighting selected options or excluding selected options from the rendered option list.

Comment: My another assumption is that component (`multi`, `Async`) won't show selected values during fetching if value prop is simple array of strings/numbers.

When using `loadOptions` function all of the values that are not found in returned options are simply not shown.

That leads me to an answer that I should take care of putting already selected options in loadOptions return. I don't want that as I want to show filtered options. I thought that maybe cache prop has purpose to keep also already fetched options, I see it in dev tools but no idea how it's used.